# Auto size div/iframe based upon content loaded inside of iframe

Tags: php, html, css, dhtml

I see alot of contradictory information on this online and I figured people here would know better than the vast majority of other places.

Is it possible to have an div with an iframe inside of it autosize the width (and possibly height) ->**WITHOUT**<- the use of javascript.. also it needs to be crossbrowser capable (browsers like lynx and ie5 are not a concern at all).

I have been tinkering and following various peoples suggestions online in regards to this for days but I still do not see my div and iframe limit their width to whatever data is loading in the iframe (just tables of random info).

Here is some of the css I have and the associated html, as you can tell it has since gone through some revisions that do not have width:auto; height:auto etc.

```
            div#topleftdiv
                {
                    float: left;
                    width: 25%;
                    height: auto;
                }

            iframe#topleftframe
                {
                    background-color: transparent;
                    -moz-opacity: .00;
                    filter: alpha(opacity=00);
                }


            div#toprightdiv
                {
                    float: right;
                    width: 25%;
                    height: auto;
                }

            iframe#toprightframe
                {
                    background-color: transparent;
                    -moz-opacity: .00;
                    filter: alpha(opacity=00);
                }

            div#topmiddlediv
                {
                    float: left;
                    width: 49%;
                    height: auto;
                    text-align: center;
                    align: center;
                    margin-left: auto;
                    margin-right: auto;
                }

            iframe#topmiddleframe
                {
                    width: 100%;
                    height: 40em;
                    text-align: center;
                    align: center;
                    margin-left: auto;
                    margin-right: auto;
                    -moz-border-radius: 15px;
                    border-radius: 15px;
                }

            div#bottomdiv
                {
                    clear: both;
                }
```

---

```
<div id="topleftdiv" scrolling="no">
    <iframe id="topleftframe" name="topleftframe" scrolling="no"  allowtransparency="true" frameBorder="0">
    </iframe>
</div>
<div id="toprightdiv" scrolling="no">
    <iframe id="toprightframe" name="toprightframe" scrolling="no" allowtransparency="true" frameBorder="0">
    </iframe>
</div>
<div id="topmiddlediv" scrolling="no">
    <iframe id="topmiddleframe" name="topmiddleframe" scrolling="no" allowtransparency="true" frameborder="0" noresize>
    </iframe>
</div>
```

Comment: What do the `src` attributes of the `iframe`s point to?

Comment: Do you mean **JavaScript** instead of **Java**? They are two entirely different languages. Also, just so you know, *dhtml* includes the use of JavaScript.

Comment: Isn't it somewhat assumed that lynx is never a real concern?

Comment: I said Java because I mean Java*, I do not want a single script or applet loaded on this page whatsoever.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it's not possible.  You need JavaScript to communicate the frame size back to the parent window.

The basic JavaScript, should you change your mind:

from the iFrame:

```
parent.document.getElementById('iframe_id').style.height =
    document.body.offsetHeight;
```

Comment: Actually it is possible.  Via iPad / webkit, it auto resizes div to iframe height.  Someone needs to research this.

Comment: @MichaelMikhjian - Actually, it's still not possible.  I haven't looked into what an iPad does exactly, but since the context of this quetion wasn't "Can I do this on an iPad", it's not possible in most other contexts, and I somewhat doubt that IOS<5 did this.  So please don't make irrelevant comments on answers that are going on 2 years old.

Comment: it wasn't a irrelevant comment, it was a comment on a 2 year old answer that may have new updates with todays standards.  What happens when someone asks the same exact question today (as that was my original intent), why not take the current high ranked / highest relevant question and update the answer directly within the page.

To be clear, iPad does support an auto height feature for iframes.

Comment: @MichaelMikhjian - I get what you're saying, but I still think it's irrelevant _in the context of this question_.  This question was looking for a cross-browser way to scale an iframe, so saying "This method works in this one specific browser" isn't a helpful answer to that.

Comment: I gotcha.  I forgot to add on, but I'm assuming that if iPad does have this support then we can expect it across all primary webkit browsers (Safari, FireFox, Chrome).  I can only assume IE9+ should / will have this support too to meet the majority of the market.  I'm hoping someone can dig on this, otherwise I'll do some experimenting  to determine the correct attributes.

Comment: I doubt it.  IOS started forcibly showing an iFrame's content no matter what, unless it's constrained in a div.  I think it was a security measure by apple, and is probably only targeted at mobile devices.